# Python 2.x - References and pointers

Tags: python, pointers, reference

I have a question. How can I get "reference-pointer effect" in Python 2.x?

I have a class, containing 2 dictionaries - 1 with character representation and 1 with integer representation (retrieved with `ord(character)`). Main problem is I will print them a lot of times, so converting them in-the-fly is a bad idea (I think). However, switching between them would be useful.

```
class Character_Dict(object):
    def __init__(self, key_length):
        self.char_dict = {}
        self.ASCII_dict = {}
        self.key_length = key_length
        self.dictionary = <<here should be a dictionary in usage>>
```

I could just assign wanted one to `self.dictionary`, but when assigning for example `self.char_dict` any change in `self.dictionary` would not apply to `self.char_dict` which in my case is a point of whole this construction.

Is there any mechanism in Python 2.x which would allow to do things like that?

[EDIT 1]:
Dictionaries contains lists of symbols encrypted with usage of n-th byte of some key:

```
n [list of character encrypted with n-th byte of key]

0 ['\xc5', '\x9a', '\xa5', '\x8d', '\xc8', '\xc8', '\x92', '\x9b', '\x82', '\x92', '\x86']
1 ['a', 'm', '.', 'a', '%', ',', ' ', '*', '$', ' ', '(']
2 ['\x18', '~', '4', '4', '?', ',', ',', '0', '9', ',', '\xe7']
3 ['\xe8', '\xe2', '\xe8', '\xec', ':', '\xe6', '\xe6', '0', '\xe6', '\xf3', '\xa9']
...
255 ['\x12', 'S', '\xcc', '_', '\xc0', 'S', '\x01', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

[EDIT 2]:
My encryption key has 256 bytes. Message which was encrypted by usage of that key is 2688 bytes long. That means that encryption key was repeated 10.5 times.

Think about changing the 3rd letter which was encrypted with usage of 10th letter of key. That's (3-1)*256+10 byte. Instead of reading that letter, I can simply read whole stream and use my class

```
fileXOR = open('2011061.xor', 'r')
key_length = 256

number_of_bytes = os.path.getsize('2011061.xor')
print number_of_bytes
amount_of_key_repetition = number_of_bytes/key_length.__float__()
print "Key has been repeated", amount_of_key_repetition, "times"

character_dict = Character_Dict(key_length)
for counter_x in range(0, key_length):
    character_dict.dictionary[counter_x] = []
print character_dict

for current_byte in range(0, number_of_bytes):
    read_character = fileXOR.read(1)
    character_dict.dictionary[current_byte % key_length].append(read_character)

fileXOR.close()
```

and I can access my character simply by:

```
character_dict.dictionary[10][2]
```

Now, imagine that I need change `character_dict.dictionary[10][2]`. In constructor I had assigned `self.char_dict` to `self.dictionary`. Changing `object_name.dictionary` will not modify `object_name.char_dict`  (AFAIK).

I want `object_name.dictionary` to be sometimes a ASCII representation, and sometimes an integer representation. That would reduce a lot of code and simplify any changes made into ciphertext.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the dicts would contain?

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: um... in python, if ``A = ObjA`` and ``B = A`` then ``B = ObjA``. Any change in the state of either ``A`` or ``B`` will be reflected in the other variable, because they're both references to the same object. In python, everything that isn't an immutable type like ``str`` or the numeric classes are references.

Comment: @aruisdante - that rule apply to standard Python dictionaries?

Comment: @juanchopanza - wait a minute, I will edit post and provide some example

Comment: @aruisdante *Every* type is a reference type. Including `str`, "numeric types", tuples, and everything else you can lay your hand on using Python.

Comment: Still no code that reproduces the problem. I am starting to suspect there is no problem to be solved.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I added an example

Comment: Why don't you just test your assumptions and see?

Comment: @aruisdante (1) Being immutable means they can't be modified means they don't behave differently when modified because they're never modified. Vacuous truth and all that. Note that plenty of things you can do with mutable types also create new objects. (2) A Python reference is indeed different from a C++ reference, but that's not related to mutability. (3) The "edge cases" relate to *interning* which merely sometimes *avoids creating objects*, not magically changes how references to such objects work. It is only related to mutability in that it's relatively transparent for immutable objects.

Comment: @aruisdante We didn't know where OP's confusion came from by the time this argument started ;-) Numbers **act like references**. One can observe the sharing (via `id` and `is`). Also, `x = ...` *always* does the same thing regardless of mutability: `A = [1]; B = A; B = [2]; print(A) # still [1]`, so OP's misconception has nothing to do with mutability, only with a misunderstanding of references and the assignment operator. Regarding `int &`: The equivalent of Python `int` is a `Integer` class that does not permit mutation, *not* `int` which is always mutable (`int i; ++i`).

Comment: @aruisdante There is no way to modify a python `int`, period. (Local name) Assignment doesn't modify *objects*. `+=` is a method call (`__iadd__`) followed by assignment, which is how is can mutate lists efficiently in-place but work for `int`s without mutation. Do you think it's weird that `S.discard(x)` modifies the set `S` but `S.union(xs)` doesn't? Both are method calls, whether they mutate depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the [weakref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) module lets you store references to objects.  If the source object gets deleted or garbage collected, this can be detected by calling the weakref.

Example from documentation:

```
>>> import weakref
>>> class Object:
...     pass
...
>>> o = Object()
>>> r = weakref.ref(o)
>>> o2 = r()
>>> o is o2
True
```

If the referent no longer exists, calling the reference object returns None:

```
>>> del o, o2
>>> print r()
None
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure what problem OP is facing, but from what I understand I don't see even the slightest relation to weak references. Care to explain how this solves what problem?

Comment: @delnan
`>>> o = Object()`
`>>> r = weakref.ref(o)`
`>>> o2 = r() `
Any change made in `o` would be applied to `o2`. The same thing I wanted in my code. Any change into `objectA.dictionary` will apply to currently assigned dictionary (ASCII or int). When I need to change current dictionary, I will just use 
`r = weakref.ref(wantedDict)`
`objectA.dictionary = r()`

Comment: @wojciechowskip But the exact same effect is achieved with `o = Object(); o2 = o`.

Comment: @delnan Does Python create a copy of that object instead of passing reference, doesn't it? And changes in `o2` will not apply in `o`?

Comment: @wojciechowskip No such thing happens. As several people already told you. Try it out. You appear to be speculating without any basis. It works. Just do it. (Also, any sane rule set which would cause a copy in `o = o2` would also cause *at least* one copy in `o = r()`.) Also, if after trying it you find that something is *actually* not working as you expect, post a [minimal](http://sscce.org/) example that displays the problem so that we can tell you what exactly went wrong (either in the code or in your thought process).

Comment: @wojciechowskip Just test that stuff before asking pointless questions.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to Python programming. A little misconception after all... Should I remove this question? Add an answer with explanation why I got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, I totally was in misconception of assigning. I was assured that every time you are assigning to `objX` there is created a copy of this `objX`. The source of this assumption was simply:

```
a = 8
b = a
b = 20
print a
>>> 8
```

I feel ashamed now. At least I understand how memory in Python is managed :)